# Inserting a portrait page into landscape presentation using beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, landscape

I am doing the presentation of my PhD using `beamer`. I have done the diagram flux of my algorithm and I want to show it in my presentation. The problem that I have is that when I wrote down the diagram flux in my `phd_doc.tex` file I didn't have any problem because the orientation of it was portrait.

But when I use the same LaTeX code of the diagram flux into `beamer.tex` file I have the problem of the orientation.

I would like to know how I can change the orientation (landscape) of a single frame in `beamer` into *portrait*? Because as I know, the orientation default in `beamer` is landscape.

Comment: If you do this, the page will display incorrectly in the presentation.  The projector won't turn round to fit the page orientation.  So the page itself probably shouldn't be changed, what should change is how your diagram fits on the page.  If you could post the code or upload a picture that would help us see what the problem is.  (As you're new to this site then to upload a picture, click the icon that looks vaguely like a picture and follow the instructions.  Then **remove the exclamation mark** from the code that's been automatically inserted.)

Comment: In order to display a beamer-formatted page in portrait mode, one would have to rotate the projector by 90 degrees (and do something with the screen too, in all likelihood). Incidentally, while it's usually OK to list an algorithm's pseudo-code on a single page, this is not the case when giving presentations (using `beamer` or any other display method). Unless your audience is already thoroughly familiar with the algorithm in question, you should work hard to break it up into smaller chunks (each with probably no more than 7 or 8 lines) and then show these smaller chunks, one per beamer page.

Comment: Here is a (positive) suggestion: Post your "diagram flux" in portrait mode, shrunk down to fit in your landscape presentation, and use `beamer`'s zooming capability to click on the "diagram flux" and zoom to fit.

Answer (score 12):

Also with beamer you could use the `landscape` environment of the `lscape` or the `pdflscape` package for changing the frame orientation - this time to portrait, since landscape is the default.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\title{The title}
\subtitle{A subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute{TeX LaTeX StackExchange}
\date{\today}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Landscape}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Some blindtext
      \item \blindtext
      \item more
      \item and
      \item more
      \item text
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{landscape}
\begin{frame}
\blindtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer portrait frame]

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the all other elements (navigation buttons, blue frame) as in landscape while rotating the content to portrait?